# Trusting individual invalid certs in mitmproxy

Tags: security, ssl, https, proxy, mitmproxy

I use `mitmproxy` to gather intel from outbound AS2 (HTTP) requests leaving our network. The schema goes like this:

```
Mendelson AS2 ➡ mitmproxy ➡ partner AS2 server
                          ↘
                           redis
```

Where possible, I need to verify all SSL certs to make sure the business connection is safe. Some partners use less known CAs which I then add to a truststore used by the `ssl_verify_upstream_trusted_ca` option.

Some partners though don't really care about security and I need to trust their certificates no matter what. How do I do that in `mitmproxy`? Disabling the verification entirely isn't an option.

Thank you.

Comment: This issue is already being discussed on GitHub: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/5019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've tried to solve this using a custom addon and it seems to work fine so I'll share it here:

https://gist.github.com/jsmucr/24cf0859dd7c9bba8eb2817d7b0bf4b6

This approach has a bit of disadvantage and that's the fact that it doesn't check if the peer certificate changes.